# Java - URL to File

Tags: java, file, url

I am trying to create a method that displays a list of files in a given directory. This works fine for normal directories (on disk) but when I enter a url my list of files is null.

```
    public void getListOfFiles(String folderLocation){
    File folder = new File(folderLocation);
    File[] listFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println(listFiles[i]);
    }
}
```

I think my problem is because the File 'folder' is removing one of the '/' in my folderLocation (http://...)

I have tried using URL and URI but have had no luck! Can anyone help?

Comment: is the location an FTP server?

Comment: If yes, I think class File is not able to handle, you need to use some kind of FTP client library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `File` won't work for this as it's not networking-aware.

Secondly, in general there's no mechanism to list files over plain HTTP. If the HTTP server gives you some kind of a listing page when you present it with the URL, you'll have to download the page using, [for example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html), [`URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) and parse it yourself.

To list files over FTP, you could use [`FTPClient`](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) from Apache Commons Net.

Comment: So I have to download the contents of the directory and then look through them myself?